# SQL (oracle) Check Constraint difficulty - Not sure how to implement

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am creating a small database for a telecom system.

One of the tables (calls) requires that a if a phone number's area code is not contained in a predefined list, then the number should not be added to the table.

The way I have thought about doing this is to put a check constraint within the calls table to not accept numbers that are not a part of this mentioned list. However, this list is quite long and I am not too sure if there would be a better implementation method.

Here is the list:

```
01 or 02: local/national number. Ex.: 01612 338866.
075, 077, 078, 079: mobile phone number. Ex.: 07747 556647.
0800: free number. Ex.: 08002 223344.
0845, 0870: special service. Ex.: 08451 423456.
08442 to 08449: 5p special service. Ex.: 08444 404404.
08712 to 08719: 10p special service. Ex.: 08713 457893.
090, 091, 098: premium rate special service. Ex.: 09119 229595.
```

The only way I could think of to do this is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE calls ADD (CONSTRAINT area_ck
 CHECK area_code ("01" or "02" or "075" or "077" or "078" or  "079" or "0800" or 
        "0845" or "0870" or (BETWEEN ("08442" AND "08449")) or 
        (BETWEEN ("08712" AND "08719")) or 
        "090" or "091" or "098")
      ) ;
```

My two main issues with this are:

1. It gives an error as it is implemented incorrectly
2. If I were to modify it slightly until it did work, would it still be a long way about        trying to solve my task?

Comment: Apropos of nothing very much, if you want to do more advanced checking of numbers, Ofcom have [files you can download](http://www.ofcom.org.uk/static/numbering/codelist.zip), or all in a [zip file](http://www.ofcom.org.uk/static/numbering/codelist.zip). You could potentially use their files as external tables and create a view of valid codes across them. I'm sure that's overkill for your problem, but might be of interest some time. Curious about why you exclude `03` numbers though.

Answer (score 5):

The more common approach would be to define a table of valid area codes

```
CREATE TABLE area_code (
  area_code VARCHAR2(5) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Fill the `Area_Code` table with the set of valid values

```
INSERT INTO area_code( area_code ) VALUES( '01' );
INSERT INTO area_code( area_code ) VALUES( '02' );
INSERT INTO area_code( area_code ) VALUES( '075' );
...
```

or

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1000 .. 2999
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO area_code( area_code )
      VALUES( to_char( i, '00000' ) );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

And then define a foreign key constraint from your `Call` table to the `Area_Code` table

```
CREATE TABLE call (
  call_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  area_code VARCHAR2(5) REFERENCES area_code( area_code ),
  <<other columns>>
);
```

That's going to be more efficient to enforce than a `CHECK` constraint and it will be easier to list the valid area codes.

Comment: Thank you very much, Justin. I will go about implementing it this way, Thanks again for your fast reply

Comment: Actually, whilst putting this method in to practice I came up with the problem that the area codes can be anything upto 5 characters, so for example:

01 or 02: local/national number. Ex.: 01612 338866.

the numbers could actually be 01000 to 02999

for the method you kindly mentioned to work, would all of these entries have to be put in to the table, or could some kind of substring manipulation be used? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @JD87 - The simplest approach would be to write a bit of PL/SQL to populate the `AREA_CODE` table.  I updated my answer with an example to populate the strings between `01000` and `02999`.

Answer (score 0):

You could either write `area_code='01' OR area_code='02'` ... or you can use `area_code in ('01','02', ...)`. You also need to add `area_code` before between keywords.

But I would suggest you to store the area codes in a table instead of the check constraint and use the area codes as foreign keys. This way the list of area codes can easily be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is about using = and between together. Do it like:

```
area_code in ('01', '02', '03') or area_code between ('1000' and '1500') or ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it looks like I am going to have a go at your method, however I am having trouble concatenating it all together, if you could have a quick look and maybe tell me where I am going wrong, that would be great, thanks


ALTER TABLE phone_calls 
ADD CONSTRAINT area_ck
CHECK rec_area_code IN ('01', '02', '075', '077', '078',  '079', '0800',  
        '0845', '0870','090', '091', '098') or (rec_area_code BETWEEN ('08442' AND '08449')
));


I have tried many different combinations of brackets and oracle keeps saying I am missing either right/left parentheses!